# Как вызвать class db?

Tags: pdo, php

Как этот класс

```
class DB{
        private $db;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');
            $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        }
    }
```

вызвать на этом классе

```
require_once 'connection.php';

class News{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DB();
    }

    public function select(){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

?

Comment: Прежде чем браться за ООП, не мешало бы почитать о области видимости, автозагрузке классов и их взаимодействии! А самое главное для чего классы вообще нужны! Имхо этот код нужно выделить и нажать кнопочку Delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас соединение с базой private. Если вы хотите без врапперов обращаться к нему - стоит сделать его public. Ваш класс приобретет вид:

```
class DB{
 public $db;

 public function __construct(){
  $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');
  $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 }
}
```

После этого вы сможете обращаться к столь заботливо обёрнутому вами объекту PDO. Вам нужно будет обратиться к полю db вашего класса, в которое вы записали объект класса DB, у которого тоже есть поле db:

```
$stmt = $this->db->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Не совсем понятно, зачем так делать, но это вполне приемлемо и ошибки тут нет.

Оффтоп: а зачем вам PDO, кстати, почему не использовать mysql_connect?

Comment: @Andrienko, почему не использовать PDO а использовать mysql_connect?

Comment: @Andrienko поставил **-** за mysql_connect

[depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto А что, лучше таки использовать PDO? Быстрее работает?

плачу горючими слезами над минусом. Ко мне придрались по мелочи и я расстроен. Настроение изгажено на весь остаток рабочего дня.

PS. Пользуюсь mysqli. По привычке называю mysql..

Comment: @Andrienko мне  нет разницы mysqli или PDO в плане скорости, хотя PDO  универсальнее конечно. 

offtopic: убийство расширения mysql это не мелочь, это весьма полезное дело.

Comment: Публичные поля в классе моветон ещё с тех пор, как я в детский садик ходил.

Comment: @VladD ничего подобного, частенько бывает случаи, когда лучше сделать паблик, чем писать методы или возиться с __get. Кому хуже от публичных полей?)

Здесь я написал про паблик потому что автор вопроса пытается обратиться к db как к паблику.

Comment: То, что автор вопроса неправильно обращается с классом — не повод для того, чтобы предлагать неправильный дизайн. Открытые поля плохи тем, что раскрывают внутренние детали устройства класса, а также в корне убивают всяческие гарантии (кто угодно может переписать значение открытого поля).

---
Кроме того, ТС пишет не `db->db->prepare()`, а `db->prepare()`, это значит, что класс `DB` должен экспортировать метод `prepare`.

Comment: @VladD ну, я исходил из того, что автор не вполне понимает, что делает)

А что плохого в "раскрытии внутренних деталей"? Что если нужен "низкоуровневый доступ" к некоторым из них? Писать геттеры и сеттеры для них, конечно, можно - но почему тогда сразу не сделать паблик? И работать будет быстрее, и мороки меньше.

Comment: @VlaD
Надо ставить вопрос по другому: делая все поля своего класса private, вы лишаете "кого угодно" возможности переписать значение открытого поля. Само собой, служебные поля не в счет, к ним доступ давать иногда даже вредно. Заставлять пользователя экстендить или реимплементить части класса - заставлять его делать лишние телодвижения. Делая которые, кстати, можно нехило накосячить. 

Если программист, использующий ваш класс, вмешивается в его работу, причем не зная, что делает - он сам себе злобный буратино. "Защите от дурака" в интерпретируемых языках не место.

Comment: @Andrienko: Раскрытие внутренних деталей убивает абстракцию: пользователь вашего класса должен держать в голове внутренние детали устройства класса. Для серьёзных, **сложных**, неигрушечных проектов это непозволительная роскошь: держать в памяти чересчур много не может никто. Низкоуровневый уровень к полям класса не нужен, если у класса разумный дизайн. По поводу полей посмотрите, например, [тут](/questions/197067/).

Comment: @Andrienko: Пользователь вашего класса не должен знать и думать, какие публичные переменные он имеет право менять, а какие нет. Он имеет право менять всё, что описано как public, для этого, собственно, public и существует. Если дизайнер класса выставляет наружу то, что на самом деле менять нельзя, он сам и виноват.

Не понял ремарку насчёт реимплементации.